# How to show Windows System Reserved partition using Ubuntu live dvd?

Tags: windows, mount, system, gparted

All questions in this site ask how to "hide"!
I want to fix my boot (fix mrb wont work, I have GPT Disk) by changing some files at Windows System Reserved. GParted shows the following partitions (but Nautilus doesn't):

```
**/dev/sda1 - file system: Unknown - 128Mb - flags: msftres** (this one shows *"Warning: Unable to detect file system! Possible reasons: -file system is damaged -file system is unknown to GParted -there is no file system available (unformated -the device entry /dev/sda1 is missing)"*)

**/dev/sda2 - file system: fat32 -100Mb - flags: boot** 

**/dev/sda3 - file system: ntfs - 500Gb**
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Nautilus (nor GParted, for that matter) can recognize the reserved partition for Windows. In fact, I don't know of any Linux tool that can.